# JSON variable not updating on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, registerclientscriptblock

I have a form to edit database values. I register a json variable using `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` on page load and then use it to check for changes to the form and prompt the user to save. In the save button click event I then re-execute the code that registers the json variable so that it contains the changes the user just saved.

The problem I've run into is the json variable is not updating to reflect the changes to the form after the postback. Only after refreshing the page does the json varable update.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Property p = Property.GetPropertyById(id);
    PopulateForm(p);
    CreateJson(p);
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Property p = Property.GetPropertyById(id);
    p.Price = txtPrice.Text.Trim();

    p.Save();
    CreateJson(p);
}

private void CreateJson(Property p)
{
    StringBuilder JSONtext = new StringBuilder();
    JSONtext.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
    JSONtext.Append("var property = ");
    JSONtext.Append("{");
    JSONtext.Append("\"price\":\"");
    JSONtext.Append(p.Price.ToString());
    JSONtext.Append("};");
    JSONtext.Append("</script>");

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "jsonVariable", JSONtext.ToString());
}
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: what do you think -  some code maybe or may not help to get an answer ?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Add `PopulateForm(p);` in `btnSave_Click` after `CreateJson(p);`

Comment: I think you should also add a `if Page.IsPostBack` check on the `Page_Load`, and only load those values when its `false`

Comment: It won't solve your question - but you are missing a closing quotation mark after your price value in your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
    {
      Property p = Property.GetPropertyById(id);
      PopulateForm(p);
      CreateJson(p);
    }
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Property p = Property.GetPropertyById(id);
    p.Price = txtPrice.Text.Trim();

    p.Save();
    CreateJson(p);
    PopulateForm(p);
}
```

It executes `PopulateForm(p)` after you've created the `json`, and in the `Page_Load` it only runs if it is not a `PostBack`

Comment: The reason this will work is because of the way the RegisterClientScriptBlock works: A client script is uniquely identified by its key and its type. Scripts with the same key and type are considered duplicates. Only one script with a given type and key pair can be registered with the page. Attempting to register a script that is already registered does not create a duplicate of the script.   From the docs: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock?view=netframework-4.7.2] (https://learn.microsoft.com)